# Issues configuring Wordpress in Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

I was successfully able to create and start to configure a wordpress site in azure.  Ran into some issues configuring the site, so I delete it in azure and started over.  After successfully creating the site again, I get a blank screen on the mysite.azurewebsites.net page.  I am not sure how to get the WP config site to appear again.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are your configurations? Without knowing that it's very difficult to help to reproduce and identify the root cause

Comment: What configuration are you talking about? Did you also delete your database or just the site? You should be more clear in your question, and perhaps read some docs on wordpress set up. There is nothing special about wordpress on azure, it's just a Web host for the standard wordpress code with a database on ClearDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've deleted your files then make sure you use right database configuration and connection in order to get your website up. For now i would say this untill you provide a excerpt of your error.logs generated on server so to figure out what is the cause of blank screen.

Comment: you are correct,  I was missed deleting the database!  Working now.